# plot differently colored background rectangles on plot over several axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code is a snippet from a much larger function that plots several financial indicators over 3 axis:

```
left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.7, width, 0.2]
rect2 = [left, 0.3, width, 0.4]
rect3 = [left, 0.1, width, 0.2]
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
axescolor = '#f6f6f6'  # the axes background color
ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1)#, axisbg=axescolor)  # left, bottom, width, height
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect2,sharex=ax1)#, axisbg=axescolor)
ax3 = fig.add_axes(rect3,sharex=ax1)#, axisbg=axescolor
```

The final plot looks like that:

[image]

Now I want to add background rectangles with a height that covers the complete x-axis (i.e. over all axis) and a width of several minutes, like that:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works :

```
ax1.axvspan(start, end, facecolor='g', alpha=0.25, label=my_label)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I marked the first answer, because it came earlier. But your solution works as well.

Comment: I have marked your solution now, since it can be achieved without importing an additional module. And unfortunately, the patches solution suggested above is not available in the ipython environment I use, since the patches module is blacklisted by the providers.

Comment: It is indeed easier !

Comment: Its more concise, but a little less flexible than the first solution. Perfect for my specific problem, however.

Comment: Simple and the best!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `patches` from `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches

left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.7, width, 0.2]
rect2 = [left, 0.3, width, 0.4]
rect3 = [left, 0.1, width, 0.2]
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
axescolor = '#f6f6f6'  # the axes background color
ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1)#, axisbg=axescolor)  # left, bottom, width, height
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect2,sharex=ax1)#, axisbg=axescolor)
ax3 = fig.add_axes(rect3,sharex=ax1)#, axisbg=axescolor
ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(
        (0.1, 0.1),   # (x,y)
        0.5,          # width
        0.5,          # height
        alpha = 0.5)) #transparency
```